# Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows

Tags: sql, select, subquery, distinct, datediff

I got this kind of table
[image: Table Actividades_Usuarios]
I already tried to obtain the following query and it works fine

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    USER_ID, SESSION_ID,
    (SELECT EVENT_TIME FROM Actividades_Usuarios 
     WHERE EVENT_ID = 1 AND USER_ID = 407) AS START_TIME_SESSION,
    (SELECT EVENT_TIME FROM Actividades_Usuarios 
     WHERE EVENT_ID = 2 AND USER_ID = 407) AS END_TIME_SESSION,
    DATEDIFF(mi, (SELECT EVENT_TIME FROM Actividades_Usuarios 
                  WHERE EVENT_ID = 1 AND USER_ID = 407),
                 (SELECT EVENT_TIME FROM Actividades_Usuarios 
                  WHERE EVENT_ID = 2 AND USER_ID = 407)) AS TIME_SESSION 
FROM 
    Actividades_Usuarios 
WHERE 
    USER_ID = 407
```

but for a single user, for example:

[image]

Then I try to make it out for the general case, setting EVENT*_*TIME as START_TIME_SESSION when EVENT_ID is 1, instead END_TIME_SESSION when EVENT_ID is 2, with the follow query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID,
       SESSION_ID,
       (SELECT EVENT_TIME FROM Actividades_Usuarios 
WHERE EVENT_ID = 1) as START_TIME_SESSION,
       (SELECT EVENT_TIME FROM Actividades_Usuarios 
WHERE EVENT_ID = 2) as END_TIME_SESSION
FROM Actividades_Usuarios
```

but get the common error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value...

when I'm looking exactly that query result. In fact, if I go run one of the column as a simple query, returns the same quantity of rows, whatever select...

```
SELECT USER_ID,SESSION_ID,
EVENT_TIME as START_TIME_SESSION 
FROM Actividades_Usuarios 
WHERE EVENT_ID = 1
```

[image]

But, how can I do this adding the other column (END_TIME_SESSION) and the final goal column result (TIME_SESSION) from `DATEDIFF` between these two?

Answer (score 1):

You need to correlate all of your subqueries i.e. add to you WHERE clauses in your subqueries something along the lines of “user id of subquery = user id of main query”

Clarifying my answer with an example…

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
A.USER_ID,
A.SESSION_ID,
(SELECT B.EVENT_TIME 
 FROM Actividades_Usuarios B
 WHERE B.EVENT_ID = 1 
 AND B.USER_ID = A.USER_ID) as START_TIME_SESSION,
(SELECT C.EVENT_TIME 
 FROM Actividades_Usuarios C
 WHERE C.EVENT_ID = 2 
 AND C.USER_ID = A.USER_ID) as END_TIME_SESSION
FROM Actividades_Usuarios A
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice @NickW I will try to figure it out, but for this case is workless to add clauses inside WHERE condition, because simply parameters 'USER_ID' or 'SESSION_ID' has no condition at all, and it could be whatever value no matter when or what reason it is insert into a new row and furter. Keep in mind is a model of a Activities Records of a HomeBanking database

Comment: So disapointed dude, this last one that you clarified, works fine for a few tests run, and then began to show the same kind of error!!! I cant freaky belive this, but is what happened. I guess there's no error in the logic or sintax of the code, might it's so a kind of issue with some internal buffer o restrinction at low level code of SQL, witch I really don't know. Because, hard to belive, the code starting to fails from one time to other without alter a simple letter!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to use is aggregation and avoid all the subqueries in the first place:

```
select USER_ID, SESSION_ID,
    min(case when EVENT_ID = 1 then EVENT_TIME end) as START_TIME_SESSION,
    min(case when EVENT_ID = 2 then EVENT_TIME end) as END_TIME_SESSION
from Actividades_Usuarios
where EVENT_ID in (1, 2)
group by USER_ID, SESSION_ID;
```

Using CTEs will make calculations a breeze:

```
with data as (
    select USER_ID, SESSION_ID,
        min(case when EVENT_ID = 1 then EVENT_TIME end) as START_TIME_SESSION,
        min(case when EVENT_ID = 2 then EVENT_TIME end) as END_TIME_SESSION
    from Actividades_Usuarios
    where EVENT_ID in (1, 2)
    group by USER_ID, SESSION_ID
)
select *, datediff(minute, START_TIME_SESSION, END_TIME_SESSION) as TIME_SESSION
from data;
```

You should also look into the way that `datediff` only counts interval boundaries. I suspect the result you want is more like this:

```
datediff(millisecond, START_TIME_SESSION, END_TIME_SESSION) / 60000 as TIME_SESSION
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @shawnt00, you're right there, this one works fine avoiding the use of subquerys. For the datediff is ok if it count interval in minutes, 'cause I looking just the tipe of Session that exced terms of 5 minutes, it's no really necesary such a precisely result of the subtraction

Comment: @Joe, you could have a "5-minute" session starting at say "1:00:59.997" and ending at "1:05:00.000". It lasted slightly more than 4 minutes of real time but `datediff` will still say 5. Or perhaps going the other way: 1:00:00.000 to 1:05:59.997 which is essentially 6 full minutes but again `datediff` still reports 5. Obviously I don't know what your result should be but be careful.